# Read Twitter feed history, take a break, return to same place, and keep reading

Tags: twitter

I took a two-month break from reading Twitter. I'd like to skim all the tweets (of the people I follow) I missed back to the last time I checked my feed. I'd break the skimming into three or four chunks. I think that if I used Twitter's website, I would be unable to pause reading and come back to the same place in my review of the tweet history.

I'm open up to any way to review all these old tweets so that I can stop and return to where I was reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read your tweets on your mobile device you can start reading it and take a snapshot as soon as you are done reading the tweets. The next time you want to start reading from where you left, just open that snapshot image saved in your phone and see its date. [Go here](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en) and then filter your tweets based on dates. This same approach will also work fine for PCs.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can I filter by date for just the people I'm following?

Comment: Yes..Go to the link i posted.

Comment: Do I have to manually add every single person I follow?